# CAverageFunctor - is something wrong with it or with VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have piece of code from certain book :)

```
class CAverageFunctor
{
private:
    double m_fSrednia;
    unsigned m_uIloscLiczb;
public:
    CAverageFunctor() : m_fSrednia(0.0), m_uIloscLiczb(0) { }

    void Reset() { m_fSrednia = m_uIloscLiczb = 0; }

    double operator()(double fLiczba)
    {
        m_fSrednia = (((m_fSrednia * m_uIloscLiczb) + fLiczba)
            / m_uIloscLiczb++);
        return m_fSrednia;
    }
};
```

In book it has its own functionality but i got interested cause of dividing by 0 :) so I modified:

```
m_fSrednia = (((m_fSrednia * m_uIloscLiczb++) + fLiczba)
                / m_uIloscLiczb);
```

As I understand it should multip. then incerment and do rest but it dont... similary 2nd:

```
m_fSrednia = (((m_fSrednia * m_uIloscLiczb) + fLiczba)
                / ++m_uIloscLiczb);
```

This should increment before dividing... so finally question: Am I missing something or VS2013 is just bad guy? Oh, and I don't want answers like: You should start with `m_uIloscLiczb(1)`. Its more about operators priority.

Comment: Your question makes little sense if any! First of all, what do you mean by "i got interested cause of dividing by 0"? Second, in the first two examples you are doing exactly the same thing (which is to divide by 0), since with `m_uIloscLiczb++` you are calling the postfix-increment operator. In the third example you are indeed using the prefix-increment operator, which prevents the division by 0. But after all that, what do you mean by "is VS2013 a bad guy"????? He's not a bad guy as long as you treat him well if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @barakmanos Well "i got interested cause of dividing by 0" means you should ignore "overall correctness" of it. Then there are 2 callings or m_uIloscLiczb - Why it isn't modified while m_uIloscLiczb++ is called but after(incrementaction is done afret m_fSrednia is done)? //well he is bad cause he dont like initialiser lists for arrays :) - so am I to add this to bad guys list or incrementation works slightly different than I thought(not done after calling but after whole expression is done)

Comment: Postfix-increment: `i++` increments `i` but returns the value of `i` before the incrementation. Prefix-increment: `++i` increments `i` and returns the value of `i` after the incrementation. The code you've tried implies that you know all this, so what exactly is the question???

Comment: Well, I thought that it will do (m_fSrednia*m_uIloscLiczb) then increment so there will be no dividing by 0 later cause /m_uIloscLiczb will be with updated value - so it is wrong for VS2013 or it would be like that for every other IDE.

Comment: If that's a question, then the answer is no - what you see is the correct behavior.

Comment: Ok that is what I wanted to know. Will you add it as answer and I mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `m_uIloscLiczb++`, you are invoking the postfix-increment operator, which returns the value of the operand **as it was before being incremented** (in your example, 0).

With `++m_uIloscLiczb`, you are invoking the prefix-increment operator, which returns the value of the operand **as it is after being incremented** (in your example, 1).